# How to calculate sum hours/day by taking into overlapping periods in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to calculate the sum of hours/per day taking into account overlapping periods in excel

---

For example:

```
Task Created                Resolved
1    2020-01-03 09:43:50    2020-01-03 11:42:22
2    2020-01-03 08:09:59    2020-01-03 17:04:51
```

Sum of hours for these 2 tasks should be 8hr54 mins instead 10hrs 52 mins
Could you please help

Comment: 1 2020-01-03 09:43:50 2020-01-03 11:42:22
************************************************************************
2 2020-01-03 08:09:59 2020-01-03 17:04:51
************************************************************************
3 2020-01-07 10:21:55 2020-01-07 15:56:52
************************************************************************
4 2020-01-07 15:16:08 2020-01-07 16:04:15
************************************************************************
5 2020-01-07 16:15:56 2020-01-08 11:35:04
************************************************************************

Comment: I believe your assumed correct duration of time is incorrect. You state 8hr54mins; that is only the time from 11:42:22 to 17:04:51. You time should be in the above scenario 9hr19min for 9:43:50 to 17:04:51

Answer (score 1):

You can try following formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((B2<$C$2:$C$7)*(INT(B2)=INT($C$2:$C$7))),AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$7*(INT(C2)=INT($C$2:$C$7)),1)-AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(INT(B2)=INT($B$2:$B$7)))*$B$2:$B$7,1),C2-B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Basic, i'm having an issue, when the task is being finished several days later, in that case, the others values that follows should be zero else it would be affect my count for the month and also for the same day, if the value is the same, one of it should be zero and the other the real value

Comment: Hi, can you supplement the question with data showing the problem and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

First format the column for time lapse. Then add this to your first cell D1

```
 =C1-B1
```

Then copy/paste this the rest of the way

```
 =sum(if(Datevalue(B2)-Datevalue(B1)=0,sum(if(B2-C1<0,C2-V1,C2-B2),D1),C2-D2))
```